# How can I enable assertions when starting Quarkus in development mode?

Tags: java, quarkus

When starting a [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) application in [development mode](https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling#development-mode) (by running `quarkus dev` in a shell), how can I enable assertions (i.e. getting Quarkus to start Java with the `-enableassertions` or `-ea` flag)?

I'd like to configure assertions to be enabled only for development mode, but not when running it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling assertions in a Quarkus application during development mode can be achieved by configuring the quarkus.vm property in your application.properties or application.yml file. So, try the steps below:

1. "application.properties"

   quarkus.vm.additionalArgs = -ea
2. "application.yml"

   quarkus:
   vm:
   additionalArgs: -ea

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I added `quarkus.vm.additionalArgs = -ea` to `application.properties`, added an `assert false;` to my code, and started the server with `quarkus dev`. It ran fine without checking any of the assertions though.